# How prove this $\frac{|x-z|}{|x-y|}=1+\frac{1}{|x|}\hat{x}\cdot(y-z)+O(1/|x|^2)$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, asymptotics

prove that
$$\dfrac{|x-z|}{|x-y|}=1+\dfrac{1}{|x|}\hat{x}\cdot(y-z)+O(1/|x|^2)$$ 
for $|x|\longrightarrow \infty$

where
$$\hat{x}=\dfrac{x}{|x|}$$
This problem from  book,following is my idea:

$$\dfrac{|x-z|}{|x-y|}=\dfrac{|x-y+y-z|}{|x-y|}=\dfrac{\sqrt{|x-y|^2+2(x-y)\cdot (y-z)+|y-z|^2}}{|x-y|}=\sqrt{1+2\dfrac{x-y}{|x-y|}\cdot(y-z)+\dfrac{|y-z|^2}{|x-y|^2}}$$
and use Taylor
$$(1+x)^a=1+ax+o(x^2),x\longrightarrow 0$$

then
$$\dfrac{|x-z|}{|x-y|}=1+\dfrac{x-y}{|x-y|}\cdot(y-z)+O\left(\left(\dfrac{x-y}{|x-y|}\cdot(y-z)\right)^2\right)$$

But I can't prove
$$\dfrac{|x-z|}{|x-y|}=1+\dfrac{1}{|x|}\hat{x}\cdot(y-z)+O(1/|x|^2)$$ 
for $|x|\longrightarrow \infty$

this problem  from 
[image]
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Please clarify: what are $x,y,z$?  Real, complex, vectors?

Comment: I think it might be better to write the third expression in your first string of equalities with dot products so that you have: $|x-y|^2+2(x-y)\cdot(y-z)+|y-z|^2$ And then (for simplicity) writing $\eta = \frac{x-y}{|x-y|}$, then repeating the process.

Comment: oh,$x,y,z$are vectors.Thank you

Comment: @CameronWilliams, can you Explain in detail？ Thank you

Comment: I think your overall procedure is good, but you washed some detail out by looking at norms like you did. Recall that $|x-y| = \sqrt{(x-y)\cdot(x-y)}$ so you have $|x-y+y-z| = |(x-y)+(y-z)| = \sqrt{((x-y)+(y-z))\cdot((x-y)+(y-z))} = \sqrt{|x-y|^2+2(x-y)\cdot(y-z)+|y-z|^2}$.

Comment: Do you see where to go from here?

Comment: You're almost there. Note that if $|x|$ is very large, $x-y$ is approximately $x$ and so the last equality becomes what you want to prove.

Comment: This problem from http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/14297417.html,and P83

Comment: oh,my frend. I mean the  following can you explain detail,not $|x-z|=\sqrt{|x-y|^2+2(x-y)\cdot(y-z)+|y-z|^2}$,Thank you